# connect Raspberry Pi 4 to a remote MySql database located on a server

Tags: javascript, mysql, arduino, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I have a new situation. I had a `javascript` running successfully on a`Arduino YUN` board that was basically querying a MySql server located on a server with an IP address (aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd). I am basically trying to replace Arduino YUN with `Raspberry Pi 4`. This is what I did to run this javascript on the Raspebrry PI.Successfully installed all the modules that were there in the Arduino YUN board and all modules, packages have been successfully installed. Now I am running to issues when trying to access MySql server from the Raspberry PI. Looks like the script is giving `null` output and I don't know how to connect the Raspberry PI to MySql server or did I make all configurations correctly as in my old board Arduino YUN.

Here is code:

```
connect2mysql = require('remote_mysql_connection.js');

var queryMySql = "SELECT product FROM catalog WHERE product_id =123;";
console.log(connect2mysql.query(mysqlQuery))
```

Here is the `remote_mysql_connection.js` script that I am importing:

remote_mysql_connection.js

```
var shell = require('shelljs');  
module.exports = {
    user: 'test',
    host: 'aa.bbb.cc.ddd',
    password: 'blahblah',
    database: 'geeko',
    async: true,

    /* Parses MySQL text output into an array of row objects. */
    parseOutput: function(output)
    {
        var rows = [];
        var outputLines = output.match(/[^\r\n]+/gm);
        console.log(outputLines);
        var columnNames = outputLines[0].split('\t');  //first line of output contains column headers
        for(var n=1; n<outputLines.length; n++)
        {
            var row = {};
            var fields = outputLines[n].split('\t');  //the values for
            for(var c=0; c<columnNames.length; c++)
            {
                row[columnNames[c]] = fields[c];  
            }
            rows.push(row);
        }

        return rows;
    },

    /* Executes a SQL query.  After the query is finished, it calls the passed callback function with the result. */
    query : function(query, callback)
    {
        var sql = "use "+this.database+"; "+query;
        var options = {silent:true, async:this.async};
        var command = 'mysql -u '+this.user+' -h '+this.host+' -p'+this.password+' -e "'+sql+'"';

        //shell.exec() runs the command, the output data is processed by the function supplied below
        shell.exec(command, options, function(code, output) {
            var result = [];
            console.log('Query:', query);
            console.log(output);

            //Parse the output if it is a select query
            if((/^(\s+)?select/i).test(query)) result = module.exports.parseOutput(output);

            if(callback) callback(result, output);  //pass result back to user supplied callback function
        });
    }
};
```

Present output:

```
null
[ 2023-01-03T14:38:56.617Z ] 'Caught exception: TypeError: Cannot read property \'0\' of null'
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
    at Object.parseOutput (/home/pi/Documents/.../remote_mysql_connection.js:15:32)
    at /home/pi/Documents/../remote_mysql_connection.js:44:63
    at /home/pi/node_modules/shelljs/src/exec.js:145:9
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:301:5)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
    at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:389:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Pipe._handle.close (net.js:607:12)
Compilation failed.
```

How to check and confirm connection between Raspberry Pi 4 and a remote MySql database located on a different server with an IP address?

**UPDATE:**

Interestingly, there seems to be a good connection between the RPi and remote MySql server (IP:'aa.bbb.cc.ddd'). How I know? I wrote a small Python script using the  same credentials as above `javascript` and `MySql` query I was using in the original program (which is JavaScript). The program ran successfully and gave the correct response. It is just a question of having all the required packages, and dependencies that support the MySql connection through JavaScript. Still don't why my `JavaScript` is not connecting to the remote `MySql` server when my `python` script connects successfully.